# Как запретить импорт определенной библиотеки в exec() python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, python-import

Возможно ли на уровне "namespace" исключить, к примеру, библиотеку *`os`*? Что бы при попытки запуска через **`exec()`** выдавалась ошибка по типу *`ImportError`*.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Раз у вы строку в exec кладете, можете сделать replace не нужного модуля, на что-нибудь подходящее вам или вообще на пустую строку .  ‘big_cmd.replace('import os', '')’

Comment: Добрый. Я тоже об этом думал. Но такую блокировку можно обойти импортом shutil , который в свою очередь импортирует os и по этому можно использовать os как 'shutil.os'

Comment: Кажется, что брать фундаментально небезопасный инструмент и с помощью костылей пытаться обезопасить его - это весьма сомнительное решение. Если не уверены на 100% во входных данных, то вообще не стоит использовать exec. Имхо.